# How can I run apex code on user login to a digital experience site?

Tags: apex, oauth2, login, digital-experience

Is it possible to run apex code on a user login to a digital experience site?  Without using a loginflow (using Apex Action in Login flow).  I do not want a user to see the loginflow interface before the login.

Comment: why not create a little LWC component without any UI, add it to the landing page of your digital experience side and let the component call an apex controller? Could this work for you?

Comment: I am sorry for the super late reply!  I have considered that approach but I would like to run the code before a user actually hits the site itself (before anything renders)